# Apply errorbars to mean-values in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I have made a ggplot of the insulin conc. at different timepoints (OGTT) for two different treatments. Afterwards I have added points showing the mean values:

```
p<-ggplot(data=data2, aes(x = factor(OGTT), y = Insulin, group = StudyID, color=StudyID)) + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(End.start ~Treatment)+ 
  stat_summary(aes(group = Treatment), geom = "point", fun.y = mean, shape = 16, size = 2)
```

My questions are:

1. How can I add errorbars to the mean value points?
2. How can I avoid that the plot shows any legends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ggplot2 cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/index.html) has answers for most fairly basic questions like this.

To add error bars, calculate the upper and lower values of the error bars separately. Then plot using `geom_errorbar()`.

http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/

To remove all legends use

```
theme(legend.position="none")
```

For more control, there are a number of other options.

http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. If the answer answers your question you can "accept it" click the tick.

Comment: I'm sorry. But I have one more question...

I only need errorbars on the mean - not for all individuals... I have calculated the sd using:
sdins<-sd(Insulin, na.rm = TRUE)

And then I have added this call...

geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=(Insulin-sdglu,ymax=Insulin+sdglu, width=.1))